# oracle sql error ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: oracle

I am getting this weird problem when I run the query, and I can't find a solution to it.

This is part of a trigger that I am running on oracle APEX.
the :old. and :new. are variable that is used for apex.

```
DECLARE
  v_old varchar2(255) := '';
  v_new varchar2(255) := '';
  v_count number := 1;
  v_sen varchar2(4000) := '';
BEGIN
  IF( :new.ASSET_ID != :old.ASSET_ID )
  THEN
    select TYPE into v_old from asset_type where id = :old.ASSET_ID;
    select TYPE into v_new from asset_type where id = :new.ASSET_ID;
    v_sen := concat(v_count, '. ');
    v_sen := concat(v_sen,concat(concat(concat('Field ASSET ID changed from ',v_old ), ' to '), v_new  ));
    v_count := v_count + 1;
  END IF;

  IF( :new.ASSET_TYPE != :old.ASSET_TYPE)
  THEN
    select TYPE into v_old from asset_type where id = :old.ASSET_TYPE;
    select TYPE into v_new from asset_type where id = :new.ASSET_TYPE;
    v_sen := concat(v_count, '. ');
    v_sen := concat(v_sen,concat(concat(concat('Field TYPE changed from ',v_old ), ' to '), v_new));
    v_count := v_count + 1;
  END IF;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_sen);

END;
```

Getting a "ORA-01008: not all variables bound" result

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong please?

Comment: And which line???  What's with the :new and :old?  this is not a trigger

Comment: Can you tell us what is it? Is it an anonymous block or is it a trigger or is it a function/procedure?

Comment: The :new and :old are variable's for oracle apex that i'm working on.
This is part of a trigger that is I am running for a table, but I removed the create trigger part

Comment: Well, it's kind of important, as is the DDL for the table the trigger is against. If it is actually a trigger, ":new and :old are variable's for oracle apex" doesn't quite make sense... Are you trying to create a trigger at runtime? What exactly are you actually running from Apex, and how are you running it?